# Reformat an Excel Database

Tags: excel, vba, database

I'm a new user to this site but come here regularly to find solutions to my Excel questions.  So first off, thank you for the information the people that answer questions give to me.  I signed up to hopefully get the same help for a specific challenge I am facing.

In the excel table I attached, the table on the top shows the current format I have a database in and I am trying to write a script to change it to the format on the bottom.

I have code (that I found on this website) that takes the value in column E and inserts rows under that amount.  However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to copy the original columns A:E to the newly inserted rows and how to reconfigure the database values in F through L to the new rows.

Is there anyone that can help me with this?  I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you.

Chris

[image]

This is the code that the forums helped me find to insert rows based on a column E.  It works, but now I am stuck.

```
Sub Insert_SB()
Dim lngCounter As Long

For lngCounter = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1


    With Cells(lngCounter, "E")

    If IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value > 1 Then
    With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Value - 1, 1)
    .EntireRow.Insert
    End With
    If IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value = 0 Then Exit For

End If
End With

Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Can the pivoted output end up on a new/separate sheet? You'll need to track which destination row is the `CurrentRow`, and then _for each_ row in the source you'll want to grab the horizontal range and transpose it onto the destination sheet + update the current row accordingly. Probably easier to do with nested loops (outer one goes down source rows, inner one goes across source columns).

Comment: Try to avoid working with offsets, it makes the code much harder to follow and reason about.

Comment: Yes, the pivoted output can go to a new sheet without issue.  Once the database is reformatted, I won't need to do it again.  However, it's thousands of rows so having a script is desired for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this without VBA by using Excel Power Query (Menu Data, "Get and Transform"). In Power Query you only have to select the columns that you want to unpivot and choose Unpivot columns. That will do the job.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I am going to check it out and give a shot.

Comment: Whoa!!  That did it!   Not only did you make this super easy, you taught me something today and I am very grateful!  Thank you!